# Find a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ isomorphic to other field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Do you know, how I can find a subﬁeld of $\mathbb{C}$ isomorphic to $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$ such that $F \nsubseteq \mathbb{R}$? I don't even have clue, how I should start.

Thanks

Comment: Can you abstractly describe $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$?

Comment: What do you mean by 'abstractly' :)? I see that basis is $1, \sqrt[3]{7}, \sqrt[3]{7^2}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\sqrt[3]{7}$ has minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ given by $f:=x^{3}-7$.  This polynomial has two complex roots, say $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (find them!), which do not belong to $\mathbb{R}$. Since each extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ given by adjoining a root of $f$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{3}-7)$, $F$ is isomorphic both to $G:=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and to $H:=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$. Since both $G$ and $H$ are not contained in $\mathbb{R}$, you are done.

Comment: Do you have any reference explaining this isomorphism part?

Comment: @michael I suppose you can look at any book about general algebra which also takes into account some field theory. You can take a look, for example, to   D.Dummit, R. Foote - Abstract Algebra, Chapter 13. However, the isomorphsim is essentially built by taking (here $F$ is any field) the only field homomorphism $F[X]\to F(\alpha)$ sending $x$ to $\alpha$ and noticing that, if $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $f$ over $F$ and $\alpha$ is (algebraic over $F$ and) such that $p(\alpha)=0$, then the kernel of that morphism must be $(p(x))$.